# unitisation of suspension of a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $A$ be a $C^*$ algebra,the suspension of $A$ is defined by $SA=\{f\in C([0,1],A)|f(0)=f(1)=0\}$,then the unitisation of $SA$ is $\tilde{SA}=\{f\in C_0([0,1],A)|f(0)=f(1)\in \Bbb C\}$.

How to prove the above conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prove that 
$$
\widetilde{SA} / SA \cong \mathbb C.
$$
The unitization of a C*-algebra is the unique unital C*-algebra with this property.